# How can I create a WebGL basic firework

Tags: javascript, webgl, point

I kinda have like a fountain of particles, but I want to make them ''explode'' making more of them where I click like a firework.

```
var nFireworks = 10000;

function initParticleSystem() {

  var particlesData = [];

  for (var i= 0; i < nFireworks; i++) {

    // angulos del cono
    var theta = Math.PI / 6.0 * Math.random();
    var phi   = 5.0 * Math.PI * Math.random();

    // direccion
    var x1 = Math.sin(theta) * Math.cos(phi) ;
    var y1 = velocity;
    var z1 = 0.0;

    // velocidad
    var alpha = Math.random();
    var velocity = (1.4 * alpha) + (0.80 * (1.0 - alpha));

    particlesData[i * 4 + 0] = x1 * velocity;
    particlesData[i * 4 + 1] = y1 * velocity;
    particlesData[i * 4 + 2] = z1 * velocity;
    particlesData[i * 4 + 3] = i * 0.095;

  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit odd, it uses velocity before it defines it, and you don't actually show the step function or anything else, but hey, I'll give it a go.

Your code (probably) generates a cone of particles where they all move along y at a constant velocity, and the x velocity is spread randomly in a PI/6 wide cone. If you want your particles to spread out in all directions randomly I would suggest starting by changing it like this:

before your for loop, set velocity to a constant first instead of all that nonsense:

```
var velocity = 5;
```

Then, you want particles to move outwards from the point in all equally random x and y directions, so change your x and y values to:

```
var x1 = ((Math.random() - 0.5) * velocity) * 2;
var y1 = ((Math.random() - 0.5) * velocity) * 2;
```

to form particles where their x and y velocities are random between -velocity and +velocity

Then, I don't know why your code generates particle data in a single array like that, I would make it

```
particleData.push([x1,y1,z1,i]);
```

and then reference each particle that way, or a possibly less performant but much more readable:

```
particleData.push({x: x1, y: y1, z: z1, brightness: i]};
```

(I'm just going to guess that i is brightness there).

Good luck buddy, it's not really a WebGL question, it's just you asking someone how to write your code for you, but hopefully that helps.